# Could not find gem 'spree_core (~> 2.0.0.beta) ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I am trying to install spree and i am using rails 3.2.9. i found that the spree 1.2.2 is only compatible with rails(3.2.9). The error i'm facing is

Could not find gem 'spree_core (~> 2.0.0.beta) ruby', which is required by gem 'spree_gateway (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.

I found that there is not any version spree_core (~> 2.0.0.beta) have released.

can anybody help me out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gem 'spree_gateway', :github => "spree/spree_gateway", :branch => "1-2-stable"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but now there is another error          **/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/devise-encryptable-0.1.1/lib/devise/encryptable/encryptable.rb:28: undefined method `add_module' for Devise:Module (NoMethodError)**